# Regex to match url with one or two segment paths

Tags: javascript, regex, nsregularexpression

I have the following url/path structure. I need a regex to match the first 2 lines. If there's a 3rd path in the url the regex shouldn't match.

Thoughts?

```
http://somewebsite.foo/aaa
http://somewebsite.foo/aaa/bbb
http://somewebsite.foo/aaa/bbb/ccc
```

Comment: Hey OP, can you post the patterns you've tried so far?

Comment: /\/aaa(\/.*|)/g  - it matches all 3

Comment: Try  using a match with an optional second part `^https?:\/\/[^\/]+\/[^\/]+(?:\/[^\/]+)?$` see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/TtJ0qb/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need regex you can use [**URL**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/URL) and [**split**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)

```js
let a = 'http://somewebsite.foo/aaa'
let b = 'http://somewebsite.foo/aaa/bbb'
let c = 'http://somewebsite.foo/aaa/bbb/ccc'

let test = (input) => {
  return new URL(input).pathname.split('/').length < 4
}

console.log(test(a))
console.log(test(b))
console.log(test(c))
```

Comment: good approach, but I'm afraid I have to use regular expression as input

Answer (score 0):

You get 3 matches because your regex `\/aaa(\/.*|)` matches 3 times a and captures a forward slash followed by any char in a capturing group matching from `/aaa` until the end of the string.

To match the full url, you could match the start of the urls and use a negated character class `[^\/]` to match not a forward slash and make the second part optional.

```
^https?:\/\/[^\/]+\/[^\/]+(?:\/[^\/]+)?$
```

- `^https?:\/\/` Match the start of the url
- `[^\/]+\` Match 1+ times not a forward slash
- `/[^\/]+` Match the first `/` followed by not `/`
- `(?:\/[^\/]+)?` Use the same pattern again only this time make it optional by using a non capturing group
- `$` End of the string

[regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/TtJ0qb/1/)

Or if it should be aaa and bbb use:

```
^https?:\/\/[^\/]+\/aaa(?:\/bbb)?$
```

```js
[
  "http://somewebsite.foo/aaa",
  "http://somewebsite.foo/aaa/bbb",
  "http://somewebsite.foo/aaa/bbb/ccc"
].forEach(x => console.log(x + " ==> " + /^https?:\/\/[^\/]+\/[^\/]+(?:\/[^\/]+)?$/.test(x)));
```